# Custom search engine

Tags: search

I have to integrate a custom search engine in a Magento installation.

Please note: before you recommend me not to change the search engine and rather to tweak the existing one, my client demands that a search services of theirs is used in this installation. So no, I can't consider other options - I have to use their custom search engine and integrate it in Magento.

What would be the best way to proceed? I think I could go with using a custom search box that will point to a non-Magento page of mine, but I'm not sure this would be a good approach. Maybe it would be better to replace the search results generation? I'm not sure either way.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the data the custom search engine returns. If it just returns the product IDs that match the query you can probably take a lot of the original `CatalogSearch` module and populate a product collection that is displayed using the out of the box templates.

If you want a little more tweaking and custom a good place to start would be to check other search modules. BubbleCode (Johan Reinke) publishes an older version of his [Elastic Search engine on Github](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-elasticsearch).

This should give you some insight into what you need to rewrite and what hooks you have to use your own service

Comment: Thanks! I will probably follow the route of basing my work on the CatalogSearch module then. Do you have any guides or articles to help me get started with that?

Comment: Hm honestly I haven't. It'll take a lot of tracing. With PHPStorm and the Magicento plugin you should be ok. At the end of the day it's just a request that retrieves data from a source so building your own controller and frontend files is also a solution